Wrong alphabetical sorting in VSC when string is in quotes
When I am using the built-in VSC sort function on some strings, it works as expected.
Unsorted:
- text.a.v3
- text.a
- text.a.v2

Sorted:
- text.a
- text.a.v2
- text.a.v3

But when I add quotes around the strings (to use it in a YAML file), the sorting order is incorrect.
Unsorted:
- 'text.a.v3'
- 'text.a'
- 'text.a.v2'

Sorted:
- 'text.a.v2'
- 'text.a.v3'
- 'text.a'

Is there a way to change this behaviour?
